# Какой алгоритм подавать в объект распределения вероятности в Random? C++

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

В заголовочном файле random присутствуют объекты, как я понял, отвечающие за распределение генерированных случайных чисел. Например uniform_int_distribution. Так вот в чем отличие этих алгоритмов от алгоритмов генерации случайных чисел? Зачем им в операторе () нужно подавать генератор и как понять какой именно требуется?
Например:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(0, 100);
```

Зачем здесь нужен mt19937 генератор? И почему нельзя использовать другой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Генератор (например `std::mt19937`) генерирует случайные **биты**. В случае `std::mt19937` биты идут пачками по 32, в `std::uint32_t`. Один набор случайных бит можно получить, вызвав на генераторе `operator()` без параметров.

Классы распределений (distribution-ы) из случайных бит делают случайные числа - в конкретном диапазоне, с определенным распределением (равномерным, или еще каким-то).

В принципе можно обойтись без классов распределений. Можно написать просто `gen() % 101`, но крутые дядьки так не делают, потому что распределение получится немного неравномерным.

> Зачем здесь нужен mt19937 генератор? И почему нельзя использовать другой?

Можно и другой. Генераторы имеют разное качество случайных чисел и разную скорость работы. Как-то традиционно из `<random>` используют `std::mt19937` - видимо выдает достаточно качественный рандом достаточно быстро.

`std::random_device` - это тоже генератор. Ему не нужен seed, и по задумке он выдает "по-настоящему рандомные" числа, платформо-зависимым способом. Обычно его не используют напрямую из-за скорости. Обратите внимание, что он [был сломан в MinGW (починен в версии GCC 9.2)](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/338/) - при каждом запуске программы выдавал одни и те же числа.

Еще обратите внимание, что от `std::mt19937` можно добиться более качественного рандома, инициализируя его другим способом, например как [тут](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/109260/97624). Вы ему на вход даете только 32 рандомных бита, а по-хорошему ему нужно 19937 бит.

Comment: Очень классно объяснили, спасибо. Не понял лишь одно. Разве набор случайных бит и случайное число - это не одно и то же? Допустим сгенерировался набор бит 1010, разве это не число 10, полученное случайно? Или же классы распределений все таки только за диапазон отвечают?

Comment: @ComeInRage По сути это число, да, но диапазон выбрать нельзя. Да, они отвечают за диапазон, и еще они могут сделать распределение неравномерным.